# Does 'netsend' or 'net send' exist?

Tags: batch-file

I've read on a lot of sites you can send "messages" over the network with the command `net send` or `netsend`. I found an easy script as a "messenger":

```
@echo off
:A
Cls
echo MESSENGER
set /p n=User:
set /p m=Message:
net send %n% %m%
Pause
Goto A
```

Now, `netsend` doesn't exist apparently and `net` doesn't contain the param `send`. Does anyone know how this is supposed to work / or is it just a joke?

Comment: This might be of some help: http://superuser.com/questions/126216/how-to-use-the-net-send-command-from-windows-7-to-windows-xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

net send doesn't exist anymore, it isn't used since vista, but there are other possibilites to achieve messaging.

https://superuser.com/questions/38967/how-do-i-get-the-net-send-messenger-service-working-on-windows-7

look here.

Answer (score 0):

there is a quite good tool called IDERI note that - among other functions - is a strong alternative to net send.

check it out: http://note.ideri.com/